# InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed while an auto-filled column is being resized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with a `DataGridView` and I want to set the columns `AutoSizeMode` to `Fill` and the grids `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode` to `AutoSize`. My problem is that if the mouse cursor accidentally hovers the upper left cell of the grid when the form loads, the application throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

This is what I should see when the form loads:
[image]
(Note how the cursor is hovering the upper left cell).

This code will provoke the exception:

```cs
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // Make sure the mouse will hover upper left cell when the form loads:
        var form = new MyForm { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual };
        form.SetDesktopLocation(Cursor.Position.X - 30, Cursor.Position.Y - 40);
        Application.Run(form);
    }

    class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
            var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            grid.Columns.Add("ColumnName", "HeaderText");
            // The form will load if I remove one of the two next lines:
            grid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            grid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            Controls.Add(grid);
        }
    }
}
```

In my configuration Visual Studio swallows the exception, so I have to run the application from Windows Explorer or command prompt to see the error.

This is the stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed while an auto-filled column is being resized.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PerformLayoutPrivate(Boolean useRowShortcut, Boolean computeVisibleRows, Boolean invalidInAdjustFillingColumns, Boolean repositionEditingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetColumnHeadersHeightInternal(Int32 columnHeadersHeight, Boolean invalidInAdjustFillingColumns)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight(Boolean fixedRowHeadersWidth, Boolean fixedColumnsWidth)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnHeadersGlobalAutoSize()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_TopLeftHeaderCell(DataGridViewHeaderCell value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.get_TopLeftHeaderCell()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellInternal(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UpdateMouseEnteredCell(HitTestInfo hti, MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnWidthChanged(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnBandThicknessChanged(DataGridViewBand dataGridViewBand)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand.set_ThicknessInternal(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AdjustFillingColumns()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ComputeLayout()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PerformLayoutPrivate(Boolean useRowShortcut, Boolean computeVisibleRows, Boolean invalidInAdjustFillingColumns, Boolean repositionEditingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Two questions targets the same issue: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934003/system-invalidoperationexception-this-operation-cannot-be-performed-while-an-au) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334647/this-operation-cannot-be-performed-while-an-auto-filled-column-is-being-resized), but the application still crashes when I apply the suggested answers.

Am I breaking some kind of best practice in the provided example?
Has anyone come across this behavior before and know a workaround?

Comment: If i don't miss nothing you don't have applied the second solution.

You play with controls in your form without suspend layout before and resuming after.

Have you try it, if yes please update code.

Comment: @Skary I tried SuspendLayout before constructing the grid and ResumeLayout after adding the grid to Controls, but it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry now i see, you do the thing in the constructor.
You can not manipulate controls here (AFIK but is not clear why, suppose something about the fact that main thread is used to draw GUI) use that event instead :
http://www.dotnetperls.com/initializecomponent
(and use it with suspend layout)

Comment: Hm, I'm getting the error even w/o hovering with a mouse. In fact my mouse in on my secondary screen and I run your snippet in VS by F5.

Comment: @Skary I think you are suggesting I move the code to the OnLoad-event. I tried that also, but it didn't help (I also tried OnLoad with SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout)

Comment: @IvanStoev That's a bit surprising. I've got only one screen here, so I can't try, but the form loads fine if I remove the line with `SetDesktopLocation`

Comment: @UlfKristiansen Forget it, I missed your code that sets the mouse position. Anyway, I identified the problem from the call stack and posted a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be a bug - the code is trying to access `dataGridView.TopLeftHeaderCell`, which when happens for the first time actually creates that cell and triggers some layout actions not expected at that moment.

With all that in mind, the fix is simple. We need to make sure that the `TopLeftHeaderCell` is created before `DataGridView` handle, by adding the following line (before addding the grid to `Controls` for instance)

```
var topLeftHeaderCell = grid.TopLeftHeaderCell; // Make sure TopLeftHeaderCell is created
```

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, Ulf, for the excellent sample showing how to reproduce this. One of my clients reported this bug to me and your sample has been invaluable.

Taking Ivan's excellent answer one step further, creating your own grid inheriting from the `DataGridView` should prevent this ridiculous bug permanently. Just be sure to always use the custom grid throughout your application.

```
public class Grid
    : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Touching the TopLeftHeaderCell here prevents
        // System.InvalidOperationException:
        // This operation cannot be performed while
        // an auto-filled column is being resized.

        var topLeftHeaderCell = TopLeftHeaderCell;

        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .net core (3.1.9) and .net5.0 this is not reproducible. There was no directly fix, but somehow there are no exception any more. See (and post if you still have this issue): https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/1830.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is related with the fact that main thread draw interface.

Actually you handle drawing (starting position) before application run is launched and before layout operation (controls) are all completly initialize inside suspend layout block.

Changing your approach solve the issue (no need to change your code, only add some pieces).

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }

    public class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
            this.InitializeComponents();
        }

        private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetDesktopLocation(Cursor.Position.X - 30, Cursor.Position.Y - 40);
        }

        private void InitializeComponents()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual ;

            var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            grid.Columns.Add("ColumnName", "HeaderText");
            // The form will load if I remove one of the two next lines:
            grid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            grid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            Controls.Add(grid);

            this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.MyForm_Shown);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Skary, but in this solution you move the form after the grid has loaded. My problem is that the exception is thrown if the cursor happens to be in the upper left corner when the grid loads. The line that contains `SetDesktopLocation` in my example is there to simulate the user accidentally hovering the cell when the form loads.

Comment: Ah sorry i miss understood your problem, i have thought that was a requirements :(
But if i remove that line, even if i place mouse over the grid (while it loading) nothing happen because suspend layout is setted (so mouse should not notify nothing to winform).
Am i missing something again ?

Comment: Look at the picture in my question. If the cursor happens to be where the upper left cell is going to be rendered, the exception is thrown. But the cursor must be there before the form loads to provoke the exception.